# Xamarin Forms CircleImage with source from file

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using a plugin CircleImage from https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/ImageCircle

I'm using it in a listview. I noticed it's working fine with image from a url but I can't find a way to show an image from embedded resources or files. Could you explain me how do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is the image in your `Resources` folder on iOS and Android platforms and in the root on Windows Phone?

You probably want to use the following to set the source of a local image:

```
Source = ImageSource.FromFile("someimage.png")
```

Or you might even try:

```
Source = (FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile("someimage.png")
```

Also be careful with upper and lower case file names. I suggest making everything lower case. The iOS simulator will not care about casing (since Macs do not care), but a real iOS device will care.

Answer (score 0):

For other developers I write and describe my solution for that. I have a MVVM model. In this model there is property

```
ImageSource image
```

when I fill the data in the model (r in the example) I verify if taking an embedded image or an image from file system

```
if (images.Count == 0) {
   // from file
   r.Image = ImageSource.FromFile ("GenericImageFromResource.png");
} else {
   // get the file image from file system 
   //(required an implementation for each platform)
   r.Image = ImageFinder.GetImage (images.First().FileName);
}
```